# Forward all emails sent to AWS subdomain to one single account

Tags: domain-name-system, email, amazon-web-services, email-server, mx-record

I have many email addresses, one for each user, on a subdomain like so: 
`username@upload.mywebsite.com`.

I'd like to receive all of these emails into one Inbox for me to use, 
e.g. `combineduploads@mywebsite.com`.

I'm using AWS Workmail and Route 53. I'm not sure where to start. Maybe this can be done with DNS records?

Answer (score 0):

Set a wildcard MX record for your domain and have it point to amazon's email servers.

You can then set up Workmail to a single email address by specifying rewriting rules.

Comment: My MX record is working and I'm receiving emails now with SES. I'm not sure about the rewriting rules though. Do you know how this can be done in Workmail or SES? I can have SES go to Lambda which then does the rest, but ideally it's simpler...